# How much does my potioneer have to dilute her potions before she can be confident her customers aren't spiking drinks with them?

Tags: magic, urban-fantasy

In my setting, potions are created by boiling magically-imbued plant and animal matter and exposing it to a soul gem, which is the crystalized MANA (magical DNA) of a dead magical creature. The resulting liquid tends to be visually indistinguishable from the liquid inside an activated glowstick. The liquids are bright neon colors, and constantly emitting about that level of light for as long as they're fresh and magically active.

One character in my story is an expert at making them, and runs her own shop where she sells all manner of potions, from medicinal to performance-enhancing to recreational, to even the most debilitating of narcotics. She has an *extremely* liberal attitude about potioneering and believes that anyone has the right to put whatever they want into their own body. However, the key phrase there is *their own* body. She's well aware that plenty of the stuff she sells could be used for horrible things if they were slipped into unsuspecting people's drinks.

Thankfully, she has a fairly realistic way to prevent this. Potions have a property known as md/L, which stands for Minute-Doses per Liter. A minute-dose is an amount of potion that will supply the potion's effects for one minute, so a potion's md/L represents how long the effects will last if you drink an entire liter of potion. In addition, at least one minute-dose must be consumed before further consumption of potion will imbue any effects at all. So consuming a single minute-dose or less will not result in experiencing any potion effects at all.

A potion's md/L is largely down to how it is brewed and how thoroughly the ingredients are concentrated. But crucially, a potion's md/L has basically no effect whatsoever on the potion's physical appearance. At basically any concentration, the liquid of the same sort of potion will be virtually indistinguishable visually.

So, naturally, the lower the potion's md/L, the more you have to consume before you experience any effects, and the harder it will be to mix it into an unsuspecting person's drink in sufficient quantities to drug them, without them noticing that someone's clearly poured something bright, colorful and literally light-emitting into their drink.

The only question is, how low does she need to bring the md/L before she can be confident the potion is safe to sell?

**Assuming that potion liquids mix properly with most known liquids, how large does a single minute-dose have to be before any drink that has been spiked with potion will look obviously abnormal?**

Comment: So you're effectively asking at what level would someone notice additional volume in their drink. That seems highly dependent upon the drink in question, I'm not going to notice a change in volume in my 1L water bottle that I forget in my car for days at a time, that I would immediately notice in a small dram of the finest whiskey that I'm slowly savoring.

Comment: @sphennings No, I mean more at what amount someone will notice that something brightly-colored and glowing has been mixed into what they're drinking.

Comment: Agree with sphennings, this question depends on the drink and the time of day the victim is poisoned with it. The magic fluid may glow, but in bright sunlight you won't notice that. Also it makes a difference if you put potion in a glass of mineral water, a cup of tea of a cup of chocolate milk. Potion in chocolate milk won't be noticed at all, even when it glows.

Comment: If your potions are strong acid and you introduce them to a drink that's mostly water I can guarantee you'll notice that! I can't guarantee your safety though.

Comment: This depends on how bright is brightly glowing, so it can't give a precise answer.  Also, if she can *dilute the effectiveness* of the potions without diluting the brightly-glowingness, then she ought to be able to add more brightly-glowingness to her concentrated potions to ensure that even a drop will be noticed.

Comment: Guinness or stout drinks aren't going to show anything unless you pretty much mix them 50/50. Pewter tankards in flickering candle light when you're blind drunk and just doing the bicep drink-to-lip curl automatically will disguise anything. People feel put out if their fancy cocktails *don't* glow. I think you need: 1) to be more specific about the conditions. 2) make it clear how this is a worldbuilding problem not a story-writing one.

Comment: Besides the issue of the obvious large amount of liquids and condition that nobody can just give an answer to cover them all
Why not make magical containers that turn a certain color when the drink is magical? 
You can imagine a club/bar getting a lot of those and making it clear to it's customers that they are not having any magic in their drinks without them knowing. 
Obviously there will be recreational magic but I digress. 
Also not sure why the character bothers. Almost anything can be used for evil, 
it's up to the person doing it. But that's just me.

Comment: I'm in one of those awkward positions where I *love* the question, up voted it, and closed it. Frankly, +1 just for the idea of md/L! But here's your problem: there's too many variables. Strength of color, viscosity, odor, solubility in the target fluid (there's a HUGE difference between syrup and alcohol) and not to mention some of them glow. The maximum md/L will vary for each and every potion. Think about it. How much milk can you put into coffee before you notice there's milk in it? How much gin? How much motor oil? There's simply no single best answer here. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

### Make the potions smell bad

There's nothing she can mix in her lab that will guarantee that a would-be victim is alert, and also guarantee they are drinking from a clear container or at least one with an open top.

Her best bet is probably to give all her potions noxious odors. Yes, that will make drinking them unpleasant, but odors can't be "masked" as reliably as light or color can. (This is why drug-sniffing dogs are so hard to fool.<sup>tho it's not impossible</sup>) And, the person who drinks the potion can hold their nose, which really will mitigate the effects of the bad smell.

---

In the real world, we tell people who go out to (1) never let their drink out of their sight, and (2) stop drinking from any drink they have lost confidence in.

As long as there are people trying to dose other people, it's going to come down to that.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different factors at work here -- the minute dose of the potion and its appearance in relation to other drinks.  Personally, I think this will create a two-axis answer to your question.

Likewise, it is probably the same thing your potion seller will have to consider for every one of her potions, likely individually or based on type of effect.

**TL;DR**:  The dosage will have no affect on the looks, and as such doesn't exactly answer the question as written, but one does not have to worry about a potion if it isn't strong enough to actually drug somebody.  The appearance part ultimately will boil down to "It Depends" -- some people are more observant and/or paranoid than others.

#### Shiny Potions

The major thing here is how powerful is a potion's glow, and how will that glow be reduced as it is mixed into mundane drinks.  If it still maintains the same glow and it was already bright to begin with, then it may take less to notice the glow than if the glow got weaken when diluted mundanely.

The next factor is how attentive one is to their drinks while they are out.  While it is common knowledge to not drink from anything you don't trust, it only takes a second or two for a skilled sleazeball to drug a drink.  And if said sleazeball has the trust of the person drinking, then they have all the time in the world to drug them.

Assuming that they don't notice the glow for whatever reason, consider colour.  If your yellow cocktail is suddenly green, it's a good clue that something blue and glowy was added to it.  The same for any change of colour from what you know a drink should be coloured.  While harder to notice for dark coloured drinks, the glow might be noticed.

Likewise the glass will also help -- a clear glass or bottle might show a glow more than an more opaque bottle.  Dosing a mixed drink in a clear glass is likely a bit easier to notice than adding a bit to an already more opaque brown beer bottle.  In this scenario, it might be a good time to get Corona -- they are served in clear bottles.

Ultimately, this comes down to memory and observation.  Given the world around a person, how obvious is a change in their drink.

**Mitigating dosing**

Ideally, she will aim to make the brightest potions given that the other senses were not mentioned in your question.  As potency is independent of brightness, her goal will be the brightest potions she can create reliably, then dilute it to a useful, but safe dose

I would assume that they would have a taste to them, based on the ingredients used.  I have not factored that into this answer so far, but making sure they have a distinct taste that is easy to point out in most to all drinks may also be a good way to tell.  It might not prevent getting a small dose from the initial contact, but it will prevent something nastier.

#### The Minute Dose

Your rules are twofold:

- One minute-dose of a potion must be consumed to begin to feel the effects
- Additional minute-doses of potion will add that much time to a potion.

The first way to ensure that people can't be dosed into oblivion is to make sure that it isn't potent enough to really affect people long enough for them to get into serious trouble.  That is a function of math basically and is independent from people noticing what is in their drinks.

As a comparison, consider pills that are used to dose up the unsuspecting.  A small pill can affect a person for hours.  Let's say four hours to put a number on things.

Second assumption:  Your potions are in 1/2 ounce servings, or roughly 15mL.  They could me more, or less, but I'm trying to think of a size that would make some sense as something that would be easy to travel with and be fairly unsuspecting if one really tried.

Using those two numbers, for a 15mL dose of a potion to have an last for 240 minutes, means that your potion has a potency of 16,000 md/L if I have my math right. Technically the dosed would be affected for 239 minutes but who's counting.

For the same 15mL potion to have no effect, that 15mL dose needs to be dose needed for one minute of effect.  Throwing numbers into a calculator because I'm too lazy to do it manually, I get a potency of 66.7md/L to be unaffected by a potion serving of that size.

To be safe, I would ensure that the potency is below that lower number.  A potency of 40md/L would mean that you need 25mL of a potion before a person feels anything, slightly less than an ounce here.  Even if they drank a US pint of the stuff (~473mL), somehow missing the glowing drink as a whole, the effect would last roughly 18 minutes.

Depending on the effect you are going for, 18 minutes could be plenty or barely enough to register the fun.  It is definitely long enough for bad things to happen, but I would guess that if they have drank all that, they either want to, or are already too far gone for that to be the cause of the problem.

**Dosing Issues**

The issue here is, of course, that there is a balance between having it weak enough that people can't be dosed against their will, and strong enough so that something that people will want will last long enough for the effect to be worthwhile.

This is a business optimization question that your potion seller will have to consider when creating and marketing her potions.  No amount of care and caution on her part will ever fully stop somebody from using her wares in ways that she can't predict and/or control.  Her dilemma will be how far on the dosage scale will she want to go.

#### Worldbuilding Tip

Unless these potions are an anomaly in your world, there are likely ways and things that can be done and used to check for these potions.  Clubs specially might have things to detect unauthorized potions in their premises -- either at the door, or available for people to use to check their own things.

To put it another way, there are likely countermeasures and antidotes that likely exist to help mitigate the effects of being potioned.